# How to extract N150R firmware from .img file

Tags: firmware

I'm trying to mount an img file for my wireless router firmware but I can't seem to do it successfully.

When I fun the file command on that .img it returns the following:

```
$ file file.img 
file.img: data
```

When I try to use mount on it I get the following:

```
$ sudo mount file.img test/
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
```

When I try to tell to use "-t auto" I get the same output:

```
$ sudo mount -t auto file.img test
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
```

xxd returns the following:

```
$ xxd -a N150R-V1.0.0.5_1.0.1.img | head
0000000: 6465 7669 6365 3a4e 3135 3052 0a76 6572  device:N150R.ver
0000010: 7369 6f6e 3a56 312e 302e 302e 355f 312e  sion:V1.0.0.5_1.
0000020: 302e 310a 7265 6769 6f6e 3a0a 0000 0000  0.1.region:.....
0000030: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
*
0000070: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1232  ...............2
0000080: 3036 3132 d9cf 3fc1 5297 2c87 0033 eed0  0612..?.R.,..3..
0000090: 9f05 0000 9f05 0000 9b63 9e62 0505 0700  .........c.b....
00000a0: 4e31 3530 522d 5631 2e30 2e30 2e35 5f31  N150R-V1.0.0.5_1
00000b0: 2e30 2e31 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  .0.1............
```

binwalk gives the following:

```
$ binwalk N150R-V1.0.0.5_1.0.1.img 

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
192           0xC0            Squashfs filesystem, big endian, version 3.0, size: 3403472 bytes, 1024 inodes, blocksize: 65536 bytes, created: 2013-11-28 11:44:07
```

fdisk (on OS X) returns:

```
$ fdisk N150R-V1.0.0.5_1.0.1.img 
Disk: N150R-V1.0.0.5_1.0.1.img  geometry: 26/4/63 [6656 sectors]
Signature: 0x95EB
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: 02  648  41  48 -  107 220  28 [ 275573942 - 2530152094] XENIX /     
 2: C9  165 158   8 -  311  15  40 [1825336399 - 3160300718] <Unknown ID>
 3: 12  606 153  51 -  988 164  42 [3547124620 - 4171149652] Compaq Diag.
 4: BD  479 182  60 -  173 155  40 [2642289636 - 1573814809] <Unknown ID>
```

Could I get some guidance on how to extract the files from the img?  I have access to both OS X and Ubuntu.

[Link to Firmware](http://support.on-networks.com/article_details/n150r-firmware-version-1005#N150R)

EDIT 1:
Result of sasquatch:

```
$ sasquatch N150R-V1.0.0.5_1.0.1.img 
SquashFS version [24373.11825] / inode count [1312449891] suggests a SquashFS image of a different endianess
Non-standard SquashFS Magic: devi
Reading a different endian SQUASHFS filesystem on N150R-V1.0.0.5_1.0.1.img
Filesystem on N150R-V1.0.0.5_1.0.1.img is (13663:12590), which is a later filesystem version than I support!
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The SquashFS image is version 3.0 with LZMA compression; LZMA compression was not officially added to SquashFS until version 4.0, so standard SquashFS tools won't recognize it.

However, [sasquatch](https://github.com/devttys0/sasquatch) extracts it just fine for me. In fact, if you have sasquatch installed, the latest version of binwalk will use it to auto-extract the file system if you run binwalk with the `-e` option.

**UPDATE:**

You need to give `sasquatch` the SquashFS image, not the raw firmware image. First, extract it with `dd` and then run `sasquash` against the extracted file:

```
$ dd if=N150R-V1.0.0.5_1.0.1.img bs=192 skip=1 of=fs.squashfs
$ sasquatch fs.squashfs
```

The latest version of `binwalk` does this for you automatically with the `-e` option:

```
$ binwalk -e N150R-V1.0.0.5_1.0.1.img
```

You can force older versions of `binwalk` to use `sasquatch` as well:

```
$ binwalk --dd='squashfs:squashfs:sasquatch %e' N150R-V1.0.0.5_1.0.1.img
```

Comment: I have updated the main post with the output from sasquatch.  It didn't work =/

Comment: You need to give sasquatch the SquashFS image, not the raw firmware image. I've updated my answer above with details.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I really appreciate your help!  Could you explain how the dd command extracts the file image?

Comment: The dd command above just copies data from the input file ('if=N150R-V1.0.0.5_1.0.1.img') to some output file of your choosing ('of=fs.squashfs'). You want to *start* copying bytes at offset 192, which is where the squashfs image starts, according to binwalk. So, just set the copy block size to 192 bytes ('bs=192'), and tell dd to skip the first block, i.e., skip the first 192 bytes ('skip=1').

Comment: That explanation was perfect.  Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to install yet another tool, it will probably mount if you strip off the header (the first 192 Bytes that binwalk talks about):

```
dd if=file.img of=file.squashfs bs=192 skip=1
sudo mount file.squashfs test/
```

EDIT:

Since the router seems to have a big-endian Mips processor, mounting didn't work for me either. The following worked on Ubuntu 14.04 however:

```
apt-get install liblzo2-dev 
git clone https://github.com/devttyS0/sasquatch
make
sasquatch /path/to/file.squashfs
```

(Obviously, you need `git`, `make`, `gcc` installed as well. `liblzo2-dev` was the only dependency i hadn't installed before. I had to used the file prepared with `dd` as shown above, not the original .img).

In case you can't get it to work, here's the extracted file:

https://mega.co.nz/#!xFoQkZRB!lcdUdDVGKsgEeu8Q5HnL3BSBXJKCHe0jZkGwOyTSxlQ

Comment: This didn't work for me.  Thank you though

Comment: Even if the image was little endian, it unfortunately would still likely not mount due to the non-standard compression. Embedded SquashFS images tend to be a PITA unfortunately.