# Extract Web Contents From Cisco Firmware Data IMG File

Tags: firmware

I download firmware

```
https://software.cisco.com/download/home/284973404/type/284971397/release/1.1.4.1
```

I extract with binwalk

```
sudo apt-get install -y binwalk'
binwalk -eM Sx220-R1.1.4.1.bin
cd _Sx220-R1.1.4.1.bin-0.extracted/_vmlinux_org.bin.extracted/_28A000.extracted/cpio-root
```

I work with sqfs.img, want mount or extract

See file command

```
$ file sqfs.img
sqfs.img: data
```

I try mount

```
$ sudo mount -o loop sqfs.img sqfs
mount: cpio-root/sqfs: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on 
/dev/loop2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

See fdisk -l

```
$ fdisk -l sqfs.img
Disk sqfs.img: 5 MiB, 5193728 bytes, 10144 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

See parted

```
$ sudo parted sqfs.img
GNU Parted 3.2
Using cpio-root/sqfs.img
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print
Error: cpio-root/sqfs.img: unrecognised disk
label
Model:  (file)
Disk cpio-root/sqfs.img: 5194kB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:
```

I read

[How to extract N150R firmware from .img file](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6720/how-to-extract-n150r-firmware-from-img-file)

I try dd

```
 $ dd if=sqfs.img of=file.squashfs bs=192 skip=1
 27049+1 records in
 27049+1 records out
 5193536 bytes (5.2 MB, 5.0 MiB) copied, 0.0968263 s, 53.6 MB/s
```

I try mount again

```
 $ sudo mount file.squashfs sqfs/
 mount: _Sx220-R1.1.4.1.bin-0.extracted/_vmlinux_org.bin.extracted/_28A000.extracted/cpio-root/sqfs: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

I try sasquatch

```
$ sasquatch file.squashfs
SquashFS version [40316.27519] / inode count [-143619237] suggests a SquashFS image of a different endianess
Non-standard SquashFS Magic: ▒<W▒
Reading a different endian SQUASHFS filesystem on file.squashfs
Filesystem on file.squashfs is (31901:32619), which is a later filesystem version than I support!
```

What can try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `binwalk v2.1.2b`, after unpacking the cpio archive `28A000`, the squashfs-root file system is available as a directory on my machine.

```
_Sx220-R1.1.4.1.bin.extracted/_vmlinux_org.bin.extracted/_28A000.extracted $ ls
5CB1A0.squashfs  CDFB8.squashfs  squashfs-root  squashfs-root-0   <----------------
```

Within this directory were folders named `cgi` and `cgi-bin`, which contain several MIPS Linux ELF32 binaries. I assume this is what you are interested in.

```
_Sx220-R1.1.4.1.bin.extracted/_vmlinux_org.bin.extracted/_28A000.extracted/squashfs-root/home/web $ ls
cgi  cgi-bin  css  extHelp  help  home.html  html  images  index.html  js  lang  login.html  logo  mime.types  tmp
```

---

```
_Sx220-R1.1.4.1.bin.extracted/_vmlinux_org.bin.extracted/_28A000.extracted/squashfs-root/home/web $ ls cgi/
get.cgi  httprestorecfg.cgi  httpuploadbakcfg.cgi  httpuploadlang.cgi  httpuploadruncfg.cgi  login.cgi  set.cgi
```

---

Please check your version of `binwalk`; if it is older than v2.1.2b you need to uninstall your older version and install the current version.

The current version can be installed by first cloning the [`binwalk` repository on github](https://github.com/ReFirmLabs/binwalk) and then following the [installation instructions](https://github.com/ReFirmLabs/binwalk/blob/master/INSTALL.md).

Note that you may also need to install [`sasquatch`](https://github.com/devttys0/sasquatch).

Comment: I cloned, installed deps, and installed binwalk... Binwalk v2.1.2-00dd062, Do I need to check out a branch? I did not get the same results you did...

Comment: what command did you issue to binwalk?

Comment: @Roman I used the same command as you, `-eM`, to extract everything at once

Comment: Is that the same commit hash as you?

Comment: @Roman Your version is now up to date. If there is still a problem with the squashfs data, try installing [sasquatch](https://github.com/devttys0/sasquatch) and unpacking the firmware again